# SQLite in Ruby: Prepared statement cutting UTF-8 input

Tags: ruby, sqlite, prepared-statement

I'm having an issue where variables are cut when they contain special characters.
This is a complete reproducable program that should run in irb:

```
require 'sqlite3'
db = SQLite3::Database.new ":memory:"
db.query "CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, key TEXT, value TEXT)"
db.query "INSERT INTO test(key, value) VALUES(?, ?)", "foo", "baræøå"
db.get_first_value "SELECT value FROM test"
```

This yields:

```
=> bar
```

If I have understood it correctly, the database should default to UTF-8, and indeed, if I edit the database with an editing tool and insert "æøå" at the end of the string, ruby is able to select it and output it correctly. Did I miss something or is this a bug?

**EDIT**

This only seems to reproducable in irb on Mac OS X. If your configuration is anything else, please disregard this question.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using Ruby 2.1.0 and SQLite 3.8.7.2. The default encoding depends on which SQLite library function creates the database. You can check the encoding with `db.encoding` in irb. What version of Ruby? What version of SQLite? (`db.get_first_value "select sqlite_version()"`)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' This is Ruby 2.0.0 on Mac OS 10.0.1, sqlite 3.7.4. I am also not able to reproduce this in Ubuntu with Ruby 2.1.0, but the problem is still present when run as a script on Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't reproduce in a script using Ruby 2.0.0 or 2.1.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64-bit.

Comment: Ok, so I actually solved my problem. I never got the UTF-8 part into my query since I used a regexp what matched with `\w` which only matches ascii. I should have used `[[:word]]`. Now my scripts works as expected. This, then, is nothing more than a "irb on mac" curiosity. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(We tried in an IRC session)
Entering the code for him resulted in:

```
irb(main):004:0> db.query "INSERT INTO test(key, value) VALUES(?, ?)", "foo", "bar\U+FFC3\U+FFA6\U+FFC3\U+FFB8\U+FFC3\U+FFA5"
```

Since `"æ"` is `"\u00e6"` and not `"\uffc3"` it was evident that the data got corrupted on entry.
`Readline::VERSION` revealed that his ruby was built against EditLine instead of Readline. Editline is OS X' broken Readline replacement.

Replacing editline with readline should solve this issue.

**Edit:**

Using escape sequences instead of literal UTF-8 would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby might be assuming your file and source code are US-ASCII. This is in contrast with the string pulled from your DB, which will be marked as UTF8.

Try adding this magic comment to the top of your file in order to enforce a different one:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Comment: I tried this, and I tried `value.force_encoding("UTF-8")`, neither of which worked.

Comment: What does `"baræøå".encoding` return? (I get UTF-8 on a Mac, but that's possibly because UTF-8 is being used system-wide.)

Comment: I get the same, both on Mac and Ubuntu. The weird thing is that it's not reproducable in irb on Ubuntu, but the problem is still there when running it as a script on Ubuntu.

Comment: I was meaning from within your script on a machine that has the problem, not in IRB on a machine that doesn't. :-)